# i am installed a theme for wordpress ..but now showing the warning messege

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am receiving the following warning message and don't know why.

```
[02-Feb-2024 04:20:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "before" on array in /home/favoursh/public_html/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 273
[02-Feb-2024 04:20:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "link_before" on array in /home/favoursh/public_html/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 275
[02-Feb-2024 04:20:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "link_after" on array in /home/favoursh/public_html/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 275
[02-Feb-2024 04:20:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "after" on array in /home/favoursh/public_html/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 277
```

Here is the class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Nav Menu API: Walker_Nav_Menu class
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 4.6.0
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement an HTML list of nav menu items.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker
 */
class Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {
    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var string[]
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent',
        'id'     => 'db_id',
    );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );

        $atts          = array();
        $atts['class'] = ! empty( $class_names ) ? $class_names : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 6.3.0
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the `<ul>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $class    HTML CSS class attribute.
         * }
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts       = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_attributes', $atts, $args, $depth );
        $attributes = $this->build_atts( $atts );

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul{$attributes}>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent  = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     * @since 5.9.0 Renamed `$item` to `$data_object` and `$id` to `$current_object_id`
     *              to match parent class for PHP 8 named parameter support.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output            Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $data_object       Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth             Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args              An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $current_object_id Optional. ID of the current menu item. Default 0.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        // Restores the more descriptive, specific name for use within this method.
        $menu_item = $data_object;

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $menu_item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $menu_item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $menu_item->ID;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $menu_item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string[] $classes   Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $menu_item, $args, $depth ) );

        /**
         * Filters the ID attribute applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_item_id The ID attribute applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args         An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth        Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $menu_item->ID, $menu_item, $args, $depth );

        $li_atts          = array();
        $li_atts['id']    = ! empty( $id ) ? $id : '';
        $li_atts['class'] = ! empty( $class_names ) ? $class_names : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu's list item element.
         *
         * @since 6.3.0
         *
         * @param array $li_atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<li>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $class        HTML CSS class attribute.
         *     @type string $id           HTML id attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $li_atts       = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_attributes', $li_atts, $menu_item, $args, $depth );
        $li_attributes = $this->build_atts( $li_atts );

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $li_attributes . '>';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $menu_item->attr_title ) ? $menu_item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $menu_item->target ) ? $menu_item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $menu_item->target && empty( $menu_item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = $menu_item->xfn;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $menu_item->url ) ) {
            if ( get_privacy_policy_url() === $menu_item->url ) {
                $atts['rel'] = empty( $atts['rel'] ) ? 'privacy-policy' : $atts['rel'] . ' privacy-policy';
            }

            $atts['href'] = $menu_item->url;
        } else {
            $atts['href'] = '';
        }

        $atts['aria-current'] = $menu_item->current ? 'page' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
         *     @type string $aria-current The aria-current attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts       = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $menu_item, $args, $depth );
        $attributes = $this->build_atts( $atts );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $menu_item->title, $menu_item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title     The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
         * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $menu_item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output  = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;


        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $menu_item   Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $menu_item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 5.9.0 Renamed `$item` to `$data_object` to match parent class for PHP 8 named parameter support.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output      Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $data_object Menu item data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth       Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Builds a string of HTML attributes from an array of key/value pairs.
     * Empty values are ignored.
     *
     * @since 6.3.0
     *
     * @param  array $atts Optional. An array of HTML attribute key/value pairs. Default empty array.
     * @return string A string of HTML attributes.
     */
    protected function build_atts( $atts = array() ) {
        $attribute_string = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( false !== $value && '' !== $value && is_scalar( $value ) ) {
                $value             = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attribute_string .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        return $attribute_string;
    }
}
```

This is the section which throws the errors:

```php
  $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $menu_item, $args, $depth );

  $item_output  = $args->before;
  $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
  $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
  $item_output .= '</a>';
  $item_output .= $args->after;

  /**
   * Filters a menu item's starting output.
```

I want to remove the logg errors, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use the `$object->property` syntax on an `$array['key']` which is why you are receiving the error. You just need to use the correct syntax for working with arrays to solve your problem.

The issue appears to occur in this section where `$args` is rewritten from an `object` to an `array`

```php
/**
 * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param WP_Post  $menu_item Menu item data object.
 * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 */

$args = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_args', $args, $menu_item, $depth);
```

Now that `$args` is an `array` and no longer an `object` you must use the `$array['key']` syntax. So making the following changes should solve your issue.

```php
$title = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_title', $title, $menu_item, $args, $depth);

$item_output  = $args['before'];
$item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
$item_output .= $args['link_before'] . $title . $args['link_after'];
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= $args['after'];

/**
 * Filters a menu item's starting output.
```

If you want to keep `$args` as an `object` and you are using php7.4+ you can cast the `array` to a `stdclass|object` by making the following change. But be sure to test that it does not break any of the expected behaviors as `$args` is used several more times after this line of code.

```php
// Cast the array to a stdclass object
$args = (object) apply_filters('nav_menu_item_args', $args, $menu_item, $depth);
```

This ensures that `$args` stays an object.